# How to get one field value from Sqlite request?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, c#-4.0

I use this function to make query:

```
public SQLiteDataReader returnDataReader(string txtQuery)
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = Openconn();
                cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
                SQLiteDataReader rd;
                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                return rd;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd = null;
            }
        }
```

And this is my query:

```
 SQLiteDataReader data = db.returnDataReader("SELECT created_at FROM Transactions ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1");
```

I tried to get value of `created_at` field from query like as:

```
string res = data["created_at"].ToString();
```

It returns me error.
Also I have checked this query directly in Sqlite manager. It works and return one row.

**Error is:**

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred   HResult=0x80131509
>   Message=No current row   Source=System.Data.SQLite   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.CheckValidRow()    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)    at
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.get_Item(String name)    at
>   Ukraine.StatisticService.lastsync() in
>   D:\Projects\c-tests-ukraine\Ukraine\Library\StatisticService.cs:line
>   25    at Ukraine.Main.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\Projects\c-tests-ukraine\Ukraine\Main.cs:line 81    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: What error did you see? Please report the exact error message received

Comment: I added error to question

Comment: Have a look at [DbCommand.ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calling ExecuteReader is not enough. Initially any kind of DataReader is positioned before any row retrieved. You need to call Read on the reader to position it on the first row returned

```
SQLiteDataReader data = db.returnDataReader(.....);
if(data.Read())
{
    string res = data["created_at"].ToString();
    ....
}
```

or add a loop

```
SQLiteDataReader data = db.returnDataReader(.....);
while(data.Read())
{
     ..get data from your rows here
}
```

However I don't consider your approach to return a SqlLiteDataReader a good practice. The reader depends on the connection being open and the connections are objects that you should really close as fast as possible to avoid dangerous resources leaks.

I suggest to use another approach to read you data

```
public void ReadData(string txtQuery, Action<SQLiteDataReader> loader)
{
    using(SQLiteConnection con = Openconn())
    using(SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(txtQuery, con))
    using(SQLiteDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(rd.Read())
            loader(rd);
    }
}
```

Then you call this method passing the delegate to the method that reads your data

```
ReadData(...querytext..., readCreatedData);
```

and then write the method *readCreatedData* that will be called by the code where you open the connection and the other disposable objects.

```
void readCreatedData(SQLiteDataReader data)
{
     string res = data["created_at"].ToString();
     .....
}
```

Finally as Rufo pointed in its comment you are really just reading a single value from a single column and this is better done using a simple ExecuteScalar

```
public string ReadString(string txtQuery)
{
    using(SQLiteConnection con = Openconn())
    using(SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(txtQuery, con))
    {
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return (result == null ? "" : result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Make this after query `SQLiteDataReader data = query`?

Comment: Well if before you have no valid instance for data, right?

Comment: @Steve Get first column value from first row is done by DbCommand.ExecuteScalar

Comment: Oh yes, missed the LIMIT 1 outside the window code.